# Ubuntu dual boot up

Tags: 14.04

If we create a bootable USB for Ubuntu and then plug it in for installing Ubuntu, then will we need to use the USB every time? Or will it be loaded even without the USB?

Comment: Would use a newer version, 18.04 or 20.04.  14.04 is end of life.  If you install to hard drive then you do not need the USB, nice to keep around if problems  happen.

Answer (score 0):

If you install Ubuntu onto the system, then you don't need to boot from the USB every time.  If you do install onto the system, there are 3 ways you can do it.

### Method 1:

You can partition your drive, and have both operating systems.

### Method 2:

You can wipe your drive, and install Ubuntu by itself.

### Method 3:

If you want all of your files, you can either back them up to a network drive/other USB, **OR** you can tell the Ubuntu installer that you want to keep your files. (I would back them up either way, just in case something goes wrong.)